# Postman: "invalid_client, Description: Unauthorized" Error when generating access token for Google Ads API

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, google-ads-api

I created new credentials in Google Developer Console  for Google Ads base  URL : https://googleads.googleapis.com/v14/customers.  and added the scope:   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords .
*Using Oauth2 user consent.* https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

> In Postman, I performed the following steps in my Google Ads workspace
> :

1a. Added Client Id and Client Secret to the variables portion of the Google Ads collection.

1. Set the token name
2. Set the grant type  = 'Authorization Code'
3. Callback URL = https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback
4. Auth URL = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
5. Access Token URL = https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
6. Scope = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords
7. Refresh token (default) = https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

> When I click the Access New Token button, I get the redirect page requesting me
> to choose an account. So I choose my google account and allow
> oauth.pstmn.io to access my google account (This is postman browser) .

The token generation fails with the message below (note that I have already successfully done token generation in Postman with credentials used for DFA Reporting for Campaigns, Sites, and Ads in GCM 360):

However, the result is that I get an "invalid client".  How could that be since I created the client in Google Developer Console and copied those over to Postman doing everything that I did successfully for GCM 360 APIs ?  Thanks. **Here are the slides:**

> Google Sensitive scopes List
> [image]

> Postman Redirect
> [image]

> Postman Error Logs
> [image]

> Response body (in error log)
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

> Two really fundamental things that I had forgotten when calling Google Ads
> whether in Postman OR in an AWS python integration (I cannot believe I missed
> this !) and they are:

1. Make sure that the client gives you a developer token
2. Make sure that your scope is non-Sensitive or, if the scope is sensitive, has been approved by Google Developer Team to allow the API to access data.

> You need both of these to make this work. I was so swayed by the
> results of the dfareporting scope working for Campaign Manager 360
> that I completely forgot the importance of scope sensitivity.
> Now I'll have to tell the client they must wait anywhere from 3 - 5 days for approval.